# Looping through a 3-d array and creating subset vectors in R

Tags: r, arrays, loops

I have the following MWE:

```
N <- 84 #Number of datasets to pull data from
dates <- c("2010.01", "2010.02", "2010.03", "2010.04", "2010.05", "2010.06", "2010.07", "2010.08",
 "2010.09", "2010.10", "2010.11", "2010.12", "2011.01", "2011.02", "2011.03", "2011.04", "2011.05",
 "2011.06", "2011.07", "2011.08", "2011.09", "2011.10", "2011.11", "2011.12", "2012.01", "2012.02",
 "2012.03", "2012.04", "2012.05", "2012.06", "2012.07", "2012.08", "2012.09", "2012.10", "2012.11",
 "2012.12", "2013.01", "2013.02", "2013.03", "2013.04", "2013.05", "2013.06", "2013.07", "2013.08",
 "2013.09", "2013.10", "2013.11", "2013.12", "2014.01", "2014.02", "2014.03", "2014.04", "2014.05",
 "2014.06", "2014.07", "2014.08", "2014.09", "2014.10", "2014.11", "2014.12", "2015.01", "2015.02",
 "2015.03", "2015.04", "2015.05", "2015.06", "2015.07", "2015.08", "2015.09", "2015.10", "2015.11",
 "2015.12", "2016.01", "2016.02", "2016.03", "2016.04", "2016.05", "2016.06", "2016.07", "2016.08",
 "2016.09", "2016.10", "2016.11", "2016.12") #list of all dates to loop through

A <- list()
for (k in seq_along(dates)) {
  A[[k]] <- read_excel(paste0("~/R/data.", dates[k], ".xlsx"), range = "B3:EO94")
}
data <- array(unlist(A), dim=c(91,144,84)) #3-dimensional array

####Problem here####
countries <- c("Can", "US")
coord <- c("15,34", "23,28")

long <- c("34", "28")
lat <- c("15", "23")

for (c in seq_along(countries)) {
for (i in seq_along(lat)) {
for (j in seq_along(long)) {
  nam <- sprintf("ci%d%d", c, i)
  assign(nam, data[i,j,])
}}}
```

I am basically trying to create two vectors that I could write individually as `Can <- data[15,34,]` and `US <- data[23,28,]`. My problem lies in me wanting to try and write data[[x,y],] to recognize the the comma within the looped value. I was wondering if there was a way around this? I don't think having a separate `i` and `j` to loop through would work because it would make 4 variables no?

I could do them individually but I have nearly 100 countries to do this for, as such, I look towards loops.

Comment: I think the issue is `data[[i],]`. Can you change it to `data[i,]`. Also the `nam` object name seems a bit strange.  Do you need `nam <- paste0("c", c,  i)`

Comment: I think you're right about the `nam`, thank you. As for the `data[i, ]` I get: `Error in data[i, ] : incorrect number of dimensions`. Further, changing it to `data[i,,]` gives me four matrices that are 144x84 when I am trying to obtain vectors that have a length of 84

Comment: Ok, it is an array, I thought it as data.frame. So, the index 'i' is slicing. through 1st dimension or. last dimension.  `data[i,,]`

Comment: 1st, so `Can <- data[15,34,]` essentially just takes all of the values (84) from each excel file for a specific coordinate 15,34. So its basically `data[15,34, all k]`

Comment: If `c` is 15, and `i` is 34, then `data[c, i, ]`

Comment: are you saying that you just need `i`? i.e. `sprintf("ci%d", i)`

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't match up to either `Can <- data[15,34,]` or the US one. But yes, I only need two vectors, one for each country, so that I can extend this to multiple countries

Comment: Yes, because you are using the index from `seq_along` it should be `assign(nam, data[as.integer(lat[i]),as.integer(long[j]),])` I updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can modify the loop to

```
for (c in seq_along(countries)) {
   for (i in seq_along(lat)) {
    for (j in seq_along(long)) {
     #nam <- sprintf("s%s%s", countries[c], lat[i], long[j])
     #Or with `paste`
     nam <- paste0(countries[c], lat[i], long[j])
     assign(nam, data[as.integer(lat[i]),as.integer(long[j]),])
  }}}
```

If we do `"[c]"` in `paste`, it won't do any interpolation.  It would be just the literal character "[c]".  We could do interpolation with `sprintf`

```
 ..
  nam <- sprintf("ci%d%d", c, i)
 ..
```

Or with `glue::glue`

```
..
 nam <- as.character(glue::glue("ci{c}{i}"))
..
```

Comment: `countries` is just a naming mechanism, the first element of `data` should be a number because its pinpointing a location in the array

Comment: @Brennan when you do `assign` it is creating an object name in the global env. and object names starting with numbers needs a backquote to call.  i.e. `assign("1c", 50);`. and then you call `1c` without backquotes, it wouldn't work.  So,  to avoid that, I used `paste0("ci_"` at the beginning i.e. `1c#
Error: unexpected symbol in "1c"#
> `1c`
[1] 50`

Comment: This creates 4 variables rather than just the two because im now looping through `i` and `j`, I will update the question to show what I have

Comment: This now creates 4 variables for each, called "Can1528, Can1534, Can 2328, Can2334" and the same for US. If I change it to `nam <- paste0(countries[c])` it gives me two, but the values dont line up with the proper one

Comment: @Brennan You are calling the `assign` from inside the third nested for loop.  What is your expected.  Here, you have 4 values and how would you want the output to return and its names

Comment: Should it go elsewhere? I am not properly understanding the logic of placement here

Comment: @Brennan If you need only two variables, created the `assign` should be created in the upper loop.  Without your expected output, I still don't understand it